# How to display a model object only for a specific time on the webpage in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to build a webapp using django framework . Below is my code for the "models.py".

```
from django.db import models


class Client(models.Model):
    SEX_CHOICES = [('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female')]
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mailid = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX_CHOICES, blank=True)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    items_onsale = models.ManyToManyField('Sinfo', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):  # for displaying the variable correctly.
        return self.fname, self.lname , self.mailid, self.sex, self.age, self.items_onsale


class Sinfo(models.Model):  # data of items put on sale by clients
    iname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    idesc = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True)

    def __str__(self):  # for displaying the variable correctly.
        return self.iname
```

**What I am trying to achieve is , display a specific instance from the object from the model , say "iname"  from Sinfo , for 1 min and then display next one . Like display item name BOOK for a min and then display next item CYCLE .**

I am able to display a single item but without any timer.

I have been looking for possible options , like using Javascript or importing timer specific libs for django BUT I am trying to achieve it using just python logic but not quite sure how things will work among the views , forms , urls scripts .

Would implementing a counter based for loop logic work ?